# Updating topology failed in Heron cluster

Tags: heron

When I tried to `update` a topology running on the `Heron Cluster`, failed message as following:
[image]
The output of update command using `--verbose` as follows:

```
[2018-07-03 12:07:27 +0800] [FINE] com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerMain: Exception when submitting topology 
com.twitter.heron.spi.packing.PackingException: Could not initialize containers using existing packing plan
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.initContainers(PackingPlanBuilder.java:259)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.addInstance(PackingPlanBuilder.java:153)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.addInstance(PackingPlanBuilder.java:141)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.binpacking.FirstFitDecreasingPacking.placeFFDInstance(FirstFitDecreasingPacking.java:312)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.binpacking.FirstFitDecreasingPacking.assignInstancesToContainers(FirstFitDecreasingPacking.java:265)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.binpacking.FirstFitDecreasingPacking.getFFDAllocation(FirstFitDecreasingPacking.java:246)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.binpacking.FirstFitDecreasingPacking.repack(FirstFitDecreasingPacking.java:180)
    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerRunner.buildNewPackingPlan(RuntimeManagerRunner.java:304)
    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerRunner.updateTopologyHandler(RuntimeManagerRunner.java:183)
    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerRunner.call(RuntimeManagerRunner.java:81)
    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerMain.callRuntimeManagerRunner(RuntimeManagerMain.java:448)
    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerMain.manageTopology(RuntimeManagerMain.java:396)
    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.RuntimeManagerMain.main(RuntimeManagerMain.java:317)
Caused by: com.twitter.heron.packing.ResourceExceededException: Insufficient container resources to add instancePlan {component-name: split, task-id: 1, component-index: 0, instance-resource: {cpu: 1.000000, ram: ByteAmount{1 GB (536870912 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{1 GB (1073741824 bytes)}}} to container {containerId=1, instances=[{component-name: spout, task-id: 3, component-index: 0, instance-resource: {cpu: 1.000000, ram: ByteAmount{1 GB (536870912 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{1 GB (1073741824 bytes)}}}, {component-name: count, task-id: 5, component-index: 1, instance-resource: {cpu: 1.000000, ram: ByteAmount{1 GB (536870912 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{1 GB (1073741824 bytes)}}}], capacity={cpu: 2.000000, ram: ByteAmount{4 GB (3758096384 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{3 GB (3221225472 bytes)}}, paddingPercentage=10}
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.getContainers(PackingPlanBuilder.java:392)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.initContainers(PackingPlanBuilder.java:256)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.twitter.heron.packing.ResourceExceededException: Adding 1.0 cores to existing 2.0 cores with 10 percent padding would exceed capacity 2.0
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.Container.assertHasSpace(Container.java:165)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.Container.add(Container.java:77)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.addToContainer(PackingPlanBuilder.java:417)
    at com.twitter.heron.packing.builder.PackingPlanBuilder.getContainers(PackingPlanBuilder.java:390)
    ... 13 more

[2018-07-03 12:07:28 +0000] [ERROR]: Could not initialize containers using existing packing plan
```

This topology is running normally, I don't know what reasons causes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies that your config doesn't set the repacking class correctly: [Creating Packing Class in Heron](https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/blob/0138b8d451c988f53e431f951f9a6fb9f2f4c116/heron/scheduler-core/src/java/org/apache/heron/scheduler/RuntimeManagerRunner.java#L362)

To solve this problem, you will need to add the corresponding config into your `packing.yaml` config file. Here is an [Example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/blob/fed30ee5a56c9d2855781c2199fea00bbd200bf4/heron/config/src/yaml/conf/aurora/packing.yaml#L19)

Comment: It seems that when repacking, the update fails due to insufficient container resources.

Comment: If both packing and repacking algorithm are `ResourceCompliantRRPacking`, there should be more aurora containers grabbed for the updating command. And if the error still occurs, could you please file a github issue [Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/issues)